# Should I use lemonade or soda pop when making a summer shandy?

Tags: fermentation, fruit, racking

So I am making a wheat beer and am adding lemons and oranges into the second stage of fermenting. I have heard through the beer vine that shandy's are lemonade and beer. Can I just add the lemonade or the soda pop before the bottling, and can it substitute the priming sugar? Also what would you recommend pop or lemonade?

Answer (score 2):

Its best to make a great wheat beer and mix it in the glass.  That's how its done traditionally and you can make it to suit your taste that day.  Just because our American commercialized culture is putting them in the same bottle doesn't mean its the best way to do it.  They have access to more tools than we do as homebrewers for controlling the post packaging outcomes regarding yeast and carbonation.

Comment: Understood. I was wondering if I added fruit in the first and second stage of fermentation stages would that help with flavoring? Or should I just wait until the second stage?